# Howto setup osm2psql

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I'm following these [instructions](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/master/README) to setup `osm2psql` . I need it to import `osm` data file inside a `PostGIS DB`.

The following steps worked fine:

```
createdb -E UTF8 -O user mydb
createlang plpgsql mydb
```

I successfully added PostGIS extensions too:

```
psql mydb < postgis.sql
psql mydb < spatial_ref_sys.sql
```

I start getting problems when trying to alter table's owner:

```
psql -d mydb -c "ALTER TABLE geometry_columns OWNER TO user"
psql -d mydb -c "ALTER TABLE spatial_ref_sys OWNER TO user"
```

both above commands produce the following syntax error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "user" LINE 1: ALTER TABLE
>   geometry_columns OWNER TO  user

I've also tried to add a semicolon at the end of the query, but I still get the same error:

```
psql -d mydb -c "ALTER TABLE geometry_columns OWNER TO user;"
psql -d mydb -c "ALTER TABLE spatial_ref_sys OWNER TO user;"
```

I'm not so confident with SQL nor with Postgres.
Could anyone tell me where's my mistake?

Comment: your user is actually called 'user'?

Comment: @tomfumb: yer it is.

Comment: looks like @JaakL beat me to it, damn time zones! http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe user is reserved keyword. You may try to put username value to semicolons. Something like:

```
psql -d mydb -c "ALTER TABLE geometry_columns OWNER TO \"user\";"
```