# Creating osm2pgsql tables in PostGIS database

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I [managed](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41620/howto-setup-osm2psql) to partially setup `osm2psql` to work with my `PostGIS` DB.

My DB contains now the following tables:

```
 Schema |       Name        | Type  | Owner 
--------+-------------------+-------+-------
 public | geography_columns | view  | user
 public | geometry_columns  | view  | user
 public | spatial_ref_sys   | table | user
```

Now I get the following error when I try to import `osm` data into it.
I'm using the following command:

```
osm2pgsql england.osm -d mydb -U user  -S default.style
```

The error I got :

```
sm2pgsql SVN version 0.70.5

Using projection SRS 900913 (Spherical Mercator)
Setting up table: planet_osm_point
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_point" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_point_tmp" does not exist, skipping
PREPARE get_way (int4) AS SELECT AsText(way) FROM planet_osm_point WHERE osm_id = $1;
 failed: ERROR:  function astext(geometry) does not exist
LINE 1: PREPARE get_way (int4) AS SELECT AsText(way) FROM planet_osm...
                                         ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Error occurred, cleaning up
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you must (in addition to other scripts you've run) also run legacy.sql file which you can find next to postgis.sql and spatial_ref_sys.sql on whatever platform you are. This will add function aliases for old names because in Postgis 2.0, all functions have a 'ST_' prefix.. so AsText is now named ST_AsTexT().

Hope this helps!